# Matlab - export image of defined size from plot

Tags: image, matlab, plot, export, patch

I am trying to export an image from a matlab plot. Here is the code:

```
clear; close all;

% parameters
image_size = 2048;
xmin = 0;
xmax = 2 * pi;

% create data
x = linspace(xmin, xmax, 100);
y = sin(x);

% create plot
patch_x = [0, x, xmax];
patch_y =  [-xmax / 2.0, y, -xmax / 2.0];
f = figure;
patch(patch_x,patch_y,'black');
axis equal;
xlim([xmin xmax]);
ylim([-xmax/2.0 xmax/2.0]);

% export plot to image of size "image_size" - this does not work as it
% should
set(gca, 'Unit', 'Pixels', 'Position', [0 0 image_size image_size]);
img = frame2im(getframe(gca));
imwrite(img,'structure.jpg')
```

The image should be exported to an image of 2048x2048 in this case - with the provided code, the image is cropped to the size of the figure. Increasing the size of the figure does not help, when the image size exceeds the desktop resolution. I already tried a lot, but nothing worked :-( Do you know any good solution for my problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: Use `export_fig` for the best results